# Delete Default Web Site before install SharePoint server 2016

Tags: sharepoint-server, installation, 2016

Hello everybody I`m a newbie in SharePoint.

I`m trying to install SharePoint server on my PC

And while I prepare the installation, I read this.

Before install, delete default web site in IIS

So I have a question. Is it okay to delete and why should I delete it???

I want to know about it.. Please somebody help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either delete the Default IIS web site or at least stop it.it use the default port 80 & 443. Which conflict with sharepoint many time.

If you notice when Sharepoint installed on a server the default web site in IIS status is stopped.

> If the default web site is accidentially started, a lot of things may
>   happen, but whatever it is, it is not good for your SharePoint health
>   :-). Therefore I recommend deleting the default web site (you don’t
>   need it in SharePoint anyway and if you ever uninstall SharePoin you
>   can always reinstall the IIS role).

[Read more here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/sharepointjoe/2011/01/19/sp2010-obscure-settings-that-might-have-a-great-impact-on-sharepoint-2010-default-web-site-in-iis/)

[Also check this](https://absolute-sharepoint.com/2013/02/troubleshooting-setting-up-an-environment-for-apps-for-sharepoint-2013.html)

Comment: wow your link is really helpful to me to understand !
Thank you Wages

Comment: No problem we are here to help you...please don't forget to upvote and mark it answer if helpful

Comment: okay If my reputation is over 15 then I`ll upvote this!

Answer (score 1):

The default website on IIS is listening to your server's port 80 and 443. After you install SharePoint and created first web application, the default hostname will be your server machine name and port 80 or 443, which is conflict with IIS default website.

Of course, if you are familiar with IIS setting and how http listener work, it is up to you to delete it or not.

I would recommend you delete it (if you are sure no website is resident on your server). Even you deleted it, it is easy to recover.

Comment: Oh thank you Mark. I understand how to handle it!!